# Conflict with the Datepicker and Tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am using a Datepicker and Tablesorter on the same View Page. The problem is if i take out the tablesorter, the datepicker is working fine but when i include again the tablesorter the datepicker is not working anymore.

Here is my code (datepicker).

```
$(function() {
var from = $('#from_h').val();
var to = $('#to_h').val();
$( "#from" ).datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',defaultDate: from,
changeMonth: true,
changeYear:true,
changeDay:true,
numberOfMonths: 1,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "fromDate", selectedDate );
}
```

});
});

Here is my tablesorter code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'custom_sort_function',
        is: function(s) {
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s) {
            return s.replace(/€/, '');
        },
        type: 'numeric'
    });


  $("#g_table").tablesorter({
      textExtraction:function(node){
      return $(node).text();
      },   
       headers: {
            0: {
                sorter: false
            },
            1: {
                sorter: false
            },
            2: {
                sorter: false
            },
            3: {
                sorter: false
            },
            4: {
                sorter: false
            },
            5: {
                sorter: false
            },
            6: {
                sorter: false
            },
            7: {
                sorter: 'custom_sort_function'
            },
            8: {
                sorter: 'custom_sort_function'
            },
            9: {
                sorter: 'custom_sort_function'
            },
            10: {
                sorter: 'custom_sort_function'
            },
            11: {
                sorter: false
            },
            12: {
                sorter: false
            },
            13: {
                sorter: false
            },
            14: {
                sorter: false
            },
            15: {
                sorter: false
            },
            16: {
                sorter: false
            },
            17: {
                sorter: false
            },
            18: {
                sorter: false
            },
            19: {
                sorter: false
            },
            20: {
                sorter: false
            },
            21: {
                sorter: false
            },
            22: {
                sorter: false
            },
            23: {
                sorter: false
            },
            24: {
                sorter: false
            },
            25: {
                sorter: false
            },
            26: {
                sorter: false
            },

        }
    });
});
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply avoid conflicting by using `jquery.noconflict()`.For more information please visit [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

here is an example-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  //your code
});
</script>
```

Comment: I already tried it, but its not working, can you show where I write this on my calendar script or in tablesorter script . I actually tried it both but no luck.

Comment: Its working now, I did'nt follow this jQuery(document).ready(function($){  that is why is not working previously. But now it works . THanks